# Dutch Option for Citizenship, father's whereabouts unknown

Tags: citizenship, netherlands, passport

I was born in 1979 to a Dutch mother and an American father. They divorced when I was very young and I have had no contact with him in over 30 years. The option requires information on my father that I simply do not have access to. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: What information is required?